# Show that a local ring is equicharacteristic iff it contains a subfield

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation

A local ring $(A,\mathfrak m)$ is equicharacteristic if $\operatorname{char} A=\operatorname{char}  \kappa (m)$.

Need hints to solve the following question:

> A local ring is equicharacteristic iff it contains a subfield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\kappa (\mathfrak m):=A/\mathfrak m$ and $\operatorname{char} A=\operatorname{char} \kappa (m)$ iff $A$ contains a field.

If $A$ contains a field $k$, then we have $\operatorname{char} A=\operatorname{char} k$ and $k\subseteq A\to A/\mathfrak m$, so $\operatorname{char}A/\mathfrak m=\operatorname{char}k$.

If $\operatorname{char} A=\operatorname{char} \kappa(\mathfrak m)$ and $\operatorname{char} \kappa(\mathfrak m)=p>0$, then obviously $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\subseteq A$. If $\operatorname{char} \kappa(\mathfrak m)=0$, then $\mathbb Z\subseteq A$ and every non-zero integer remain non-zero in $\kappa(\mathfrak m)$. It follows that every non-zero integer is invertible in $A$, so $\mathbb Q\subseteq A$.

Comment: $\operatorname{char} A=\operatorname{char} k$ and $k\subseteq A\to A/\mathfrak m$ what do you mean by $\to$?

Comment: How does it follow that every non zero integer is invertible in A.In general a unit in A/m doesnt translate into a unit in A.

Comment: $\to$ is the canonical surjection; the elements of $A$ which are not in $m$ are units, right?

Answer (score 1):

$\kappa$ is often used to mean "[residue field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_field)". If $R$ is a ring and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, the notation
$$\kappa(P)$$
means [the fraction field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) of $R/P$, and is called *the residue field at* (or *of*) *the prime $P$*.

Comment: So it means the field A/m here then

Comment: Yup, that's right!